# Discord.js & Canvacord: Error: libuuid.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, discord.js

After I added level.js file in my commands folder and ran the bot, it showed up the error:

```js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: libuuid.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/UnfortunateDistortedEngine/node_modules/canvas/lib/bindings.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/UnfortunateDistortedEngine/node_modules/canvas/lib/canvas.js:9:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
```

The code of level.js file:

```js
const { client, CommandInteraction, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const db = require('quick.db')
const canvacord = require("canvacord");
const Levels = require('discord-xp')

module.exports = {
  name: "level",
  description: "Displays the user's level and XP.",
  type: 'CHAT_INPUT',
  options: [
    {
      name: "member",
      type: "USER",
      description: "Specify a user.",
      required: false
    }
  ],
  run: async (client, interaction, args) => {
    let user1 = message.author;
    const Blacklisted = db.fetch(`blacklistedUsers_${user1.id}`)
    if (Blacklisted === true) return;
    let target = await interaction.options.getUser('member')
    let mentionedMember = target || interaction.user;
    const user = await Levels.fetch(mentionedMember.id, interaction.guild.id, true)

    const rank = new canvacord.Rank()
      .setAvatar(mentionedMember.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png', size: 512 }))
      .setCurrentXP(mentionedMember.xp || 0)
      .setRequiredXP(Levels.xpFor(user.level + 1) || Levels.xpFor(1))
      .setRank(user.position)
      .setLevel(user.level)
      .setStatus(mentionedMember.presence.status)
      .setBackground("IMAGE", "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/22/90/0f/22900f16a05211e2562828b6b3fe86b7.jpg")
      .setProgressBar("#FFFFFF")
      .setUsername(mentionedMember.username)
      .setDiscriminator(mentionedMember.discriminator);

    rank.build()
      .then(data => {
        const attachment = new MessageAttachment(data, "RankCard.png");
        interaction.followUp({
      files: [attachment]
    })
      });
    
  }
}
```

There already was an [issue](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1893) opened on GitHub, but the opener didn't state any solution, just said "Solved". This is related to the Canvacord package that uses canvas.

Comment: I found the solution btw it's [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71997150/10697213)

Answer (score 1):

*Well, if you're using [replit](https://replit.com) it's showing that error... So, I suggest you to change your replit.nix with the given nix below it would definitely fixed your issue!*

```hs
{ pkgs }: {
deps = [
pkgs.nodejs-16_x
pkgs.libuuid
];
env = {
LD_LIBRARY_PATH = pkgs.lib.makeLibraryPath [pkgs.libuuid];
};
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need `libuuid` which is a dependency of `node-canvas` which in return is a dev dependency of `canvacord`, it is usually preinstalled in many linux systems although you can use

```sh
apt-get install libuuid1
```

to install it, this should solve the issue, please note that you might have to use [Nix](https://search.nixos.org/packages?channel=21.05&show=libuuid&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=libuuid) if you are using a host such as [repl.it](https://replit.com/%7E) in which you do not have root access.

Comment: after i installed it, it still shows the same error.

Comment: the exact same problem is happening to me.. after, I even set `pkgs.libuuid` in the `replit.nix` file and it still shows the same error