# I want to use canvas but there is an error

Tags: node.js, canvas, discord.js, node-canvas, replit

Code:

```js
const { createCanvas, loadImage } = require('canvas')
const canvas = createCanvas(200, 200)
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

// Write "Awesome!"
ctx.font = '30px Impact'
ctx.rotate(0.1)
ctx.fillText('Awesome!', 50, 100)

// Draw line under text
var text = ctx.measureText('Awesome!')
ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.lineTo(50, 102)
ctx.lineTo(50 + text.width, 102)
ctx.stroke()

// Draw cat with lime helmet
loadImage('./img.jpg').then((image) => {
  ctx.drawImage(image, 50, 0, 70, 70)

  console.log('<img src="' + canvas.toDataURL() + '" />')
});
```

or I tried just import canvas it still return error

```js
const Canvas = require('canvas');
```

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: libuuid.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/FoxBot/node_modules/canvas/lib/bindings.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
```

> I just install and try a example code of canvas package (in npmjs.com) but when I run the code, there is an error. 
> I ask my friend and he said canvas in djs v13 has some errors, but I saw on youtube that someone can use canvas in djs v13 without errors.

**Why and how to fix?**

Comment: can you share the npm link of the package and also add the example you tried?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas

Comment: `cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` seems you pathing the image in the wrong path

Comment: i think that is package error not my code

Comment: @KaizOffical can you also share the example code snippet you tried?

Comment: I found this code `loadImage('examples/images/lime-cat.jpg')` in the example. It might be that you don't have the image file in this path

Comment: please also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @kritiz i try change a valid image path but it still like that

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add the snipped of code that generates the error?

Answer (score 1):

I found the way to fix this problem. (Using Replit) 
Step 1: Click on three dots button, click `Show hidden files` 
Step 2: Go to file called `replit.nix` 
Step 3: Add `pkgs.libuuid` in `deps` 
Step 4: Add `env = { LD_LIBRARY_PATH = pkgs.lib.makeLibraryPath [pkgs.libuuid]; };` under deps;

Now you can use node-canvas in replit!

Example `replit.nix` file

```hs
{ pkgs }: {
    deps = [
        pkgs.libuuid
        pkgs.nodejs-16_x
        pkgs.nodePackages.typescript-language-server
        pkgs.nodePackages.yarn
        pkgs.replitPackages.jest
    ];
    env = { LD_LIBRARY_PATH = pkgs.lib.makeLibraryPath [pkgs.libuuid]; };
}
```

Comment: I suffered from this problem and the **STEP 4** part I never thought of doing.. IT WORKS